# How to identify if file or not a file?

Tags: java

The Java methods `isFile()` and `isDirectory()` only work if the file or directory actually exists what if it doesn't exist?

Is there any alternative to those methods?

example:

```
File f=new File(var);
```

Now, `var` is anything generated from the runtime so I don't know if it is a file or not and you can actually initialize the object without the file or path existing.  What I want to get at is: how can I determine if the file is really a file even if it does not exist? If I determine if there are extensions I might be able to tell, but in Linux I think some files do not have file extensions and I need to work on all platforms.

Comment: Your example doesn't help. A nonexistent file system object is neither a file or a directory. It's like if said I want to know what model Porsche I have, even though I don't own a Porsche. Extensions are irrelevant. Yes, files without an extension are quite common on Unix. They can also exist on Windows, I believe, though happen to be less common. Likewise, it is possible to have directories with extensions (eg: "rc2.d" or "Safari.app"), so there's no reliable way to tell just from a name whether it's meant to be a directory or a file.

Answer (score 8):

If the file does not exist then it is neither a normal file nor a directory...it doesn't really make sense to ask what type of file it is if it doesn't actually exist.

If you create the file then you can decide what type it is; if you don't create the file then, well, it doesn't exist.

Comment: Even with the example it still doesn't make sense to ask if the `File` object represents a file or a directory...it is neither. If you call `f.createNewFile()` then it will become a normal file; if you call `f.mkDir()` then it will become a directory.

Answer (score 4):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile%28%29

Returns:
    true **if and only if the file denoted by this abstract pathname exists** and is a normal file; false otherwise ...

Thus, additionally checking for exists() is unnecessary.

Final input:
Just drop the concept of file extensions. It's really nothing but the filename. It's just used as metadata for other programs on a operating system so that certain files could be associated/opened with certain programs.

Comment: yeah i'm confused in this statement which i think it also denotes the filename of the file so if the path+filename does not exist is what i understand in this context am i right?

Answer (score 1):

Call the `exists()` method to determine if the file or directory exists or call `getPath()` to get the path of what the `File` object is pointing to (regardless of whether that path exists or not).

**Updated for additional information added to question.**

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check whether var is a valid string representing a valid path. Maybe something like if (var != null && var instanceof String && ((String) var).matches("regex for filesystem, underlying system dependent")) { 
//do something here
}

then you can use the exists() method to check whether the file is valid.